# Can one run linux from a folder via entry into bootloader (GRUB2 etc) rather than from a whole partition

Tags: linux, boot, system-installation, boot-loader

I would like to know if one can extract an ISO into a folder and then add an entry into the bootloader pointing to initrd and kernel and boot into this linux distro?
I know booting into linux ISO mounted as loop device is possible but I could not find a way to extract ISO or copy installed system into a folder and run that OS.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.

You would need to modify the code in the bootloader to:

1. mount the whole partition
2. bind mount the folder you want in a second directory
3. use the second directory as your root

I've done this as a mount helper, but it never occurred to me try this for root.

Answer (score -1):

You ca point to a different kernel, but the whole operating system relies on components being installed at certain absolute paths. You'd have to rebuild the whole system to change all those paths -- a job for a lifetime.

You may be able to achieve your goal by using `chroot`, but you can't directly boot into that system. You need at last some minimal boot system and then run everything else in you unpacked distro with `chroot`. Or will a VM solve your needs?

Comment: You can easily boot into a chrooted environment with a modified initramfs.  The 2 stage minimal boot and then pivot into another mounted or chrooted Filesystem is exactly what initramfs is there for.